# Live Stream from a low-end laptop

Tags: windows-10, streaming, obs-studio, twitch

I desire to stream my gameplay live on twitch using my laptop which is a one with pretty low specs. as follows:

Wifi connection with ~8Mbps upload

Windows 10 Enterprise 64-bit

Intel i3-5005u 2.00GHz processor

Integrated Intel HD Graphics 5500

6 Gb of RAM.

What OBS (not Streamlabs) settings should I adjust that my stream would be lag-free? I don't want the stream to be of very high quality but something that the viewers might understand.

Thanks.

P.S. I do not have an Nvidia or Asus or AMD GPU. Nor do I have a capture card of any kind.